# Deadlock with multithreads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock

I'm new to C and have the following multithread scenario where N-threads read from a single binary file, and write to their own separate files eg. thread 1 writes to file_1 and thread 2 writes to file_2, so on.

This works for ~2/3 threads but for anymore it seems to fall into a deadlock but I'm not sure what the source of the problem is.

Cheers! :)

```
#include "tape.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define BYTE unsigned char

int present_file = 0;
pthread_t THREADS[100];
int OFFSET[100];
FILE * file;
pthread_mutex_t read_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t finished_read_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t file_read = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t read_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t finished_read_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int read = 0;
int finished_reading = 0;
int read_value;
size_t file_length;
int n_threads = 0;

void* tape_reader(void* args) {

int offset = *((int *) args);

FILE * file_ptr;

if(present_file == 1){
    file_ptr = fopen("head1", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 2){
    file_ptr = fopen("head2", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 3){
    file_ptr = fopen("head3", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 4){
    file_ptr = fopen("head4", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 5){
    file_ptr = fopen("head5", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 6){
    file_ptr = fopen("head6", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 7){
    file_ptr = fopen("head7", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 8){
    file_ptr = fopen("head8", "wb");
}

else if (present_file == 9){
    file_ptr = fopen("head9", "wb");
}
else if (present_file == 10){
    file_ptr = fopen("head10", "wb");
}
else{
    file_ptr = NULL;
}

while(read == 0){
    pthread_cond_wait(&read_cond, &read_mutex);
}

//thread start reading

pthread_mutex_lock(&file_read);

BYTE buffer;

rewind(file);

fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET);

for(int i = 0; i < read_value; i++){

    if(i == file_length){
        i = 0;
    }
    fread(&buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file);
    fwrite(&buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file_ptr);
}

fclose(file_ptr);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&file_read);

return 0;

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

if(argc == 1){
    printf("Tape Not Inserted\n");
    return 1;
}

else if(argc == 2){

    file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Cannot Read Tape\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else{

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

        file_length = ftell(file);

        rewind(file);

        while(1){
            char userInput[100];

            int offset;

            scanf("%s", userInput);

            if(strcmp(userInput, "QUIT") == 0){
                return 0;
            }

            //printf("%s\n", userInput);

            if(strcmp(userInput, "HEAD") == 0){

                scanf("%d", &offset);

                pthread_create(THREADS + present_file, NULL, tape_reader, (void *) &offset);

                n_threads++;

                present_file++;

                if(offset >= 0){
                    printf("HEAD %d at +%d\n", present_file, offset);
                    printf("\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("HEAD %d at %d\n", present_file, offset);
                    printf("\n");

                }

            }


            if(strcmp(userInput, "READ") == 0){

                int read_for;

                scanf("%d", &read_for);

                read_value = read_for;

                read = 1;

                pthread_cond_signal(&read_cond);

                //threads read

                printf("Finished Reading\n\n");

                for(int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++){
                    pthread_join(THREADS[i], NULL);
                }

                return 0;
            }

        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: you're new to 'C' but you've jumped in at the deep end and decided to do threading?

Comment: Been doing it for 2 months and following an online lecture/week - I'd say that's still relatively new.

Comment: @Hews I'd say that's relatively new too. Surprised you're covering threads that soon,, you can't see it but I'm giving this curriculum the stink eye. Also, might I suggest something like `char filename[64] = {0}; sprintf(filename, "head%d", present_file); file_ptr = fopen(filename, "wb");` rather than that lengthy `if/else if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to problems that [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50616426/5529197) said, there is another tricky problem too. **You cannot guarantee that `present_file` in thread is the same value as what you have set outside.** This code:

```
      if(strcmp(userInput, "HEAD") == 0){

            scanf("%d", &offset);

            pthread_create(THREADS + present_file, NULL, tape_reader, (void *) &offset);

            n_threads++;

            present_file++;

            ...

        }
```

**You don't know when thread really starts.** So for example in 1st iteration, it may start after increasing `present_file` in `main` and for 2nd iteration, it starts before increasing `present_file`. Then You will have similar `present_file` for 2 different threads **leading access to same file**.

Even though this is a very tricky one and you may not see in normal conditions, it can happen. And because you say that you see this problem for higher number of threads, I think this will be the main reason for your problem.

You can use lock around accessing its value to encounter problem. Another approach that I personally prefer is to use an allocated `struct` to pass both `offset` and `present_file` to thread using argument.

```
struct params
{
    int present_file;
    int offset;
};

...

      if(strcmp(userInput, "HEAD") == 0){

            scanf("%d", &offset);

            struct params *params = calloc(1, sizeof(*params));
            params->present_file = present_file;
            params->offset = offset;

            pthread_create(THREADS + present_file, NULL, tape_reader, (void *) params);

            n_threads++;

            present_file++;

            ...

        }
```

just remember to `free` params **in thread** after reading values from it.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two errors in this part of your code:

```
while(read == 0){
   pthread_cond_wait(&read_cond, &read_mutex);
}
```

Error #1 is that you are reading the value of the `read` global variable without any serialization.  Since `read` is an `int` (and not any kind of `atomic` type), doing that invokes undefined behavior (e.g. thread A might change `read`'s value and thread B might never "see" the change)

Error #2 is that you are calling `pthread_cond_wait()` without `read_mutex` already in a locked state.  As the [pthread_cond_wait() man-page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) states:

> The pthread_cond_wait() [function is]
>   used to block on a condition variable. They are called with mutex
>   locked by the calling thread or undefined behaviour will result.

There may be other problems as well, but that's what jumps out at me.